# RSelenium with docker container and phantomjs crashing with for loop or lappy

Tags: docker, web-scraping, phantomjs, rstudio, rselenium

I am trying to scrape some information form a website in Rstudio, using RSelenium controlling a docker container running phantom js.

from docker toolbox i run :

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 wernight/phantomjs phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

from R studio i then run :

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
```

I can then use the remDr object as normal using

```
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate( "website_I_Scrape.com" )
# Etc.
```

My problem occurs as soon as i try to do an Rselenium call on an entire list using lappy or a for loop, as follows:

```
elem <- remDr$findElements( using = "css", value = ".ClassIwant" )
NAMES <- unlist( lapply( elem, function(x){ x$getElementText() } ) )
```

or

```
elem <- remDr$findElements( using = "css", value = ".ClassIwant" )
NAMES<-c()
for(i in 1:length(elem)){
TEMP_TEXT<-Provincias[[i]]$getElementText()
NAMES<-c(NAMES, TEMP_TEXT)
}
```

I do not get an error message, R just keeps running indefinately.

Any ideas about why this isnt working or how i could get around it ?